# How do I pass login_hint to gapi.auth.authorize?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I seem to recall there was a parameter to gapi.auth.authorize to specify a login_hint to bypass the account picker. But Google as I might, I can't find it. Was it just a dream?

My problem is that I'm having issues where the account picker is popping under the current window, so is being missed by the user.

Or another way of asking the question might be, how are arguments like login_hint and incremental auth https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#incrementalAuth exposed by the Javascript library?

Answer (score 10):

Google's [OAuth 2.0 documentation, under the heading Forming the URL](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl), states that a `login_hint` parameter is accepted (for example, `login_hint=email@fake.com`).

The [JavaScript Client Library documentation, under `gapi.auth.authorize`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize), states:

> If the key is not one of the expected OAuth 2.0 parameters (see below), it is added to the URI as a query parameter.

So you should be able to do  this:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    // Parameters here...
    'login_hint': 'email@fake.com',
    // ...Parameters here
}, callbackFunc);
```

The library will include the `login_hint` parameter in the request URL.

Comment: Note that you'll also need to pass `authuser: -1`. Google even does this internally: https://github.com/googledrive/zipextractor/blob/6086f0f17f5d3ee5faded4ed3da6d08c8173e52d/js/driveapi/authmanager.js#L37

Comment: @BradVogel I don't see that in the documentation…

Comment: Yup, it's undocumented.